# Como Ordenar Em R

Tags: r

Como fazer para ordenar os números na linguagem r

```
dados = order(dados, decreasing = F)
dados
```

Aqui so ordena a posição...
Queria saber um método de ordenar os números que estão na lista dados: `dados = c(8,6,5,4,1,3,7)`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o **sort**

```
dados = c(8,6,5,4,1,3,7)
dados = sort(dados, decreasing = F)
dados
```

Saída

```
1 3 4 5 6 7 8
```